# What method is called when PreferenceActivity saves values

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I have an app which uses PreferenceActivity to define time period to run scheduled tasks.
But I can't the right method to Override in PreferenceActivity to make tasks rescheduled on period values changed.

Does anyone know what method is called when PreferenceActivity saves values?
I am using API 8 level and seems that onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) is not that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback for changed preferences in a PreferenceActivity. But you can use the normal [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) that you would use everywhere else. Just register it in and you'll get notified when a preference changes. Check for the correct key in the callback and reschedule your tasks.