# Using Preference activity and views for editing sqlite data

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like to use Preference activity and views to edit sqlite data. Is Preferences only reserved reading/writing share preferences or could it also be used for sqlite as storage?

This data is rarely changed and fits perfect to put it as settings, but is not suitable storing as shared preferences since it has relationship to other data in sqlite db and it could potentially have many rows. Reusing Preferences UI would save me time making all UI  looking identically to Preference views.

My app looks very much like native android mail app and what I'm asking here could be compared to account editing through settings in mail app.

Any hint, recommendations and reference to examples/tutorials that could be useful will be appreciated.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500926/is-it-possible-to-use-preferenceactivity-with-sqlite-instead-of-res-xml

Comment: Did you managed to get it to work? If yes, could you please answer your own question posting implementation details. This would be very helpful! Thank you.