# Storing settings in Android multi-user app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

What is the best way to store user settings in Android app which is multi-user?

Now I'm using

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
 .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
String uid = sharedPref.getString("prompt-on-close", "N/A");
```

I think this won't work for me as this would mean, all users would share the same settings (if user signs out and another signs in the values remains the same).

I discovered an alternative:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I'm still not sure if this is prefarable solution and more important, if standard Prefrences dialogs can uset it. I think it uses the default settings only.

Comment: better use sqlite databse...

Comment: If there is a large amount of settings you better use SQLite. You can try things like GreenDAO if you want to have efficient fetching ;)

Comment: any way to force Preference dialogs to store data in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLlite for solving this issue,you can create rows for each users on user account creation time and update data whenever you want to,i usually use this method when i need to store a large amount of preference for multi-user applications
and this question here solves the doubt in your question in comments about PreferenceActivity [Is it Possible to Use PreferenceActivity with SQLite instead of res/xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500926/is-it-possible-to-use-preferenceactivity-with-sqlite-instead-of-res-xml)

Comment: ok, assuming it's a small app with only a few settings and the chances that two different users will use it on the same device are rather small..what about this: "pref_user1_prompt_on_close", "pref_user2_prompt_on_close".... might work if I build the key dynamically, what you think?

Comment: that's the solution for it,you can always add preference according to the username dynamically. we can eliminate the use of databases by using that method(Considering it as a small app)

Comment: oh, I forgot, I define preferenceactivities in xml, so the keys are static. Is it possible to define keys programatically so I can make them dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

you thought in a correct direction and In my opinion the best way follows following steps==>

Initialization

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Storing Data

```
// returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

Clearing / Deleting Data
If you want to delete from shared preferences you can call remove(“key_name”) to delete that particular value. If you want to delete all the data, call clear()

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Following will clear all the data from shared preferences

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Editing==>

```
Editor e = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
e.putString("password", mPassword);
e.commit();
```

Comment: sorry, you misunderstood my question